# How to make CategoryAxis background opacity = 1

Tags: amcharts4

I have a CategoryAxis on a RadarChart and I want to make the background a light grey with opacity = 0.5.

How can I do it?

```
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 15;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontWeight = "bold";
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.horizontalCenter = "right";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 0.5;
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.opacity = 0.5;
categoryAxis.renderer.axisFills.template.disabled = true;
categoryAxis.mouseEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Which background? The background of the chart, of the axis, of the series? Can you please add your complete chart config, or create a code pen?

Comment: The background of the Axis. 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/marcosfsj/pen/gyxwWv)

Comment: Another think is: whenever the graph area becomes smaller a couple of labels disappear (display=none).

Comment: Can you just edit your question and add all that information, including the complete config of your chart?

Comment: I was unable to add all the code here. Are you able to see the Codepen?

Comment: I need to now how to avoid this: (from the documentation) Normally it would be 1, but when labels start to be hidden due to minGridDistance this read-only property will increase.

How to avoid the label to disappear.